# Why is readonly array assignable to numeric dictionary?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am wondering why TS allows assigning readonly arrays to numeric dictionaries.

```js
const x: readonly string[] = []
const y: { [key: number]: string } = x
y[0] = 'asd' // this is unwanted behavior
```

I would expect a TS error on second line (assigning to y). However the code passes with no errors.

Comment: I believe you can read more about this in https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13347

Comment: And in [Microsoft/TypeScript#13002](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13002), formerly named "readonly modifiers are a joke"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @falinsky and @jcalz for your answers in comments bellow my question. I understand the reasons now.